# can't edit my h:datatable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

i have this code:

```
<h:form>
        <rich:dataTable  value="#{my.lreqs}"  var="req"
            id="reqs" width="630px"  >
                <rich:column label="Value" styleClass="schColL" width="90px"
                style="text-align:center">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{my.colValue}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:inputText value="#{req.value}" >
                </h:inputText>
            </rich:column>
        </rich:dataTable>
        <h:commandButton value="Save"
            action="#{my.saveChanges}" ></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

and this is my bean:

```
private List<Detail> lreqs;


public void setLreqs(List<Detail> lreqs) {
        this.lreqs = lreqs;
}

public void saveChanges() {

        firstNewValue = lreqs.get(0).getValue();
        }

/**
     * @return the lreqs
     */
    public List<Detail> getLreqs() {
        if (currentJob != null && lreqs==null) {
            lreqs = (List<Detail>) jobsBDataDAO.findByJobBooking(currentJob);
        }
        return lreqs;
    }
```

but when i click save - a new value in req.value field is not being saved!
why is it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include `saveChanges()` method which shows how you concluded that the new value is not been saved.

Comment: do you have setValue() method in Detail class?

Comment: How did you conclude that the new value is not been saved? Is `firstNewValue` null or so? Or was some exception been thrown? You should include any exceptions and stacktraces you got, because they contain very valuable information.

Comment: i saw that the value is the original value although i have changed it in the page and clicked submit

Comment: Is the bean request or session scoped? Show the data loading logic as well. It's impossible to nail down the root cause of the problem with the little information as far.

Comment: i have <a4j:keepAlive beanName="my" /> which means - keep alive while the view is opened. i edited the bean and added the getLreq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a mistake.

the a4j:keepAlive tag of richfaces was before f:view..
and wasn't read properly.